# C++ Monte Carlo portfolio Pricer

Tags: c++, c++11, montecarlo, quantitative-finance

I'm developing a portfolio option pricer using Monte Carlo, but I have encountered a problem. My program compiles and runs. Then I have the out of range vector when the program has to compute the portfolio price. What to do? I have attached my `Portfolio.cpp` and my `Monte Carlo.cpp`.

**PortFolio.cpp:**

```
#include "Portfolio.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

Portfolio::Portfolio(const vector<VanillaOption>& Option_){

    numberOfOptions = Option_.size();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < getNumberOfOptions(); ++i) {
        theOption.push_back(Option_[i].clone());
    }

}

shared_ptr<Portfolio> Portfolio::clone() const {
    return shared_ptr<Portfolio>(new Portfolio(*this));
}

void Portfolio::setOptionPrice(const double& price) {
optionPrice.push_back(price);
}

double Portfolio::getOptionPrice(const unsigned int& index)const {
    return optionPrice[index];
}

double Portfolio::getNumberOfOptions()const {
    return theOption.size();
}

double Portfolio::getPayOff(const unsigned int& index, const vector<double>&          spot) const {
    return theOption[(int)index]->getPayOff(spot);
}

double Portfolio::getExpiry(const unsigned int& index)const {
    return theOption[index]->getExpiry();
}

double Portfolio::getOptionValueP()const {
    double sum = 0;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i <getNumberOfOptions(); i++) {



        sum  = std::accumulate(optionPrice.begin(), optionPrice.end(),0.0) * positionValue;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

This is my MonteCarlo implementation for the portfolio:

```
PortfolioSimulation::PortfolioSimulation(const unsigned long& numberOfPaths_,     const unsigned long& numberofTimeSteps_) {
    setNumberOfPaths(numberOfPaths_);
    setNumberOfTimeSteps(numberofTimeSteps_);
}

Portfolio PortfolioSimulation::operator()(
    const Portfolio& thePortfolio_,
    vector<UnderlyingAsset>& vTheAsset_,
    const vector<shared_ptr<Process>>& vTheProcess_)const {

    //Assign passing values to local variables
    vector<shared_ptr<Process>> vTheProcess = vTheProcess_;
    Portfolio thePortfolio = thePortfolio_;
    vector<UnderlyingAsset> vTheAsset = vTheAsset_;

    const unsigned int numberOfOptions = (int)thePortfolio.getNumberOfOptions();
    vector<vector<double>> simulatedSpot(numberOfOptions,vector<double>(getNumberOfTimeSteps()));
    vector<double> runningSum(numberOfOptions,1);
    vector<double > mean(numberOfOptions,1);
    vector<double> simulatedPayOff(numberOfOptions,1);
    double time[2];

    const double numberOfPaths = getNumberOfPaths();
    const double numberOfTimeSteps = getNumberOfTimeSteps();

    //Path simulation
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfPaths; i++) {

        //Option
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < numberOfOptions; j++) {

            //Initialise values every paths
            const double step = thePortfolio.getExpiry(j) / getNumberOfTimeSteps();
            vTheAsset[j] = vTheAsset_[j]; 
            time[0] = 0;
            time[1] = step;

            //Time Steps
            for (unsigned int k = 0; k < numberOfTimeSteps; k++) {

                simulatedSpot[j][k] = (*vTheProcess[j])(vTheAsset[j], time[0], time[1]);
                vTheAsset[j].setSpot(simulatedSpot[j][k]);
                time[0] = time[1];
                time[1] += step;

            }

            simulatedPayOff[j] = thePortfolio.getPayOff(j, simulatedSpot[j]);
            runningSum[j] += simulatedPayOff[j];
        }

        }


    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < numberOfOptions; i++) {
            mean[i] = runningSum[i] /getNumberOfPaths();
            mean[i] *= exp(-vTheAsset[i].getRate()*thePortfolio.getExpiry(i));                  thePortfolio.setOptionPrice(mean[i]);
    }

    return thePortfolio;
}
```

Comment: What do you see when you debug it?

Comment: Portfolio is either 0 or error saying vector out of range. but normally thats after some weeks.

Comment: Wall clock weeks or simulated weeks? Exactly where - which access - is the failure?

Comment: tweaks I mean. Sorry